# error loading python DLL

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy comenzando en la programacion con python, hice unos ejecutables '.exe' de 2 aplicaciones que hice con python, los ejecutables los hice en la consola con pyinstaller, en mi pc me corren perfectamente pero al pasarlos a otra pc me sale n 2 errores, primero: "No se encuentra el punto de entrada del procedimiento ucrtbase.terminate en la biblioteca de vinculos dinamicos api-ms-win-crt-runtime-|1-1-0.dll" y despues me sale: "error loading python dll "C:\Users...\python36.dll" LoadLibrary: The specified procedure could not be found." ( ya busque en google pero los resultados son muy variados por problemas muy diferentes al mio :s )

Comment: Hola, @Davidasd verifica que en la máquina donde quieres ejecutar tu programa este actualizada, tenga instalada las librerías de Visual C++ (Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio) que en muchas ocasiones son requeridas para ejecutar aplicaciones.